# Selenium project to Requests

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i’ve developed a web scraper that extracts reviews from a particular shopping website. It’s coded by Python and the scraping is used based on Selenium + BS4. But my client thinks it’s TOO SLOW and wants it to be using Requests. To scrape the reviews, I have to wait until the reviews show up (or to click a review tab) and then page through for every reviews. I’m guessing the review div is an xhr element or an ajax because the whole page doesn’t load up when i click the next page. All the scrapings are used by BeautifulSoup.
I’m leaving an url so you guys can all go and check!

https://smartstore.naver.com/hoskus/products/4351439834?NaPm=ct%3Dkeuq83q8%7Cci%3Df5e8bd34633b9b48d81db83b289f1b2e0512d2f0%7Ctr%3Dslsl%7Csn%3D888653%7Chk%3D9822b0c3e9b322fa2d874575218c223ce2454a42

I’ve always thought Requests seem to read the HTML far faster than Selenium. But I don’t know how to attain the HTML when it’s all hidden by buttons. Does anybody have an idea? Or something I can refer to?

Comment: Have you tried running the `selenium` browser in headless mode?

Comment: I tried it, but in some reasons it doesn’t work! Is it mich faster that way? Do you think i should figure how to work it as headless mode?

Comment: Yes it will surely be faster, since it no longer needs to render the browser GUI. Running it headlessly is like using it solely as a JS/AJAX engine

Comment: Thank you I'll let you know after I try it.

Comment: Hello @DanBrezeanu I've tried the headless mode, it's working, it's faster, but not fast enough. Do you have any other ideas? Is there any other scraping tools that work faster than Selenium? Request can't do something like click and wait for ajax to appear and stuff, right?

Comment: No, unfortunately the `requests` module can't interact with the page. I don't think you can go faster than your current iteration, since page loading and JS loading takes sometimes a significant amount of time. Try optimizing your code as much as possible (i.e. removing unnecessary actions, reducing number of pages loaded). The overhead you're experiencing is bound to the server, not your scraping methods.

Comment: I've fixed the problem after reading this article. https://www.codementor.io/@codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi